# Cone projected tangent angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, projection

A cone has a slope of 45 degrees.
The cone is projected on a plane that is inclined to the axis of the cone by x degrees.
If x was 0, the projection would be 2 lines converging at 90(45 + 45) degrees to each other.

[cone projection parallel to cone's axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpQzd.png)

If x was 90 degrees, the projection would cover the infinite plane in all directions.

[cone projection perpendicular to cone's axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMota.png)

In fact, if x is anything greater than the cone's slope(45 degrees), the projection will completely cover the plane.

[cone projection at roughly 80 degrees between projected plane and cone's axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXAXT.png)

If x was 45 degrees, the projection would be a straight line because one side of the cone would be perfectly perpendicular to the projected plane.

[cone projection with 45 degrees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H26dZ.png)

If x is between 0 and 45, the projection will be 2 converging lines at a point representing the vertex of the cone.

[cone projection around 20 degrees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofbM0.png)

**Question 1:**
If the cone is projected at an angle of x between 0 and 45 degrees, what expression represents the angle between these converging lines?

[illustration of projected tangent lines from the cone and angle in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaaYl.png)

**Question 2:**
If the cone's slope was represented by y degrees instead of being a constant 45, what expression would represent the angle between the converging lines for x between 0 and (90 - y) degrees?

Comment: Welcome to mse. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Andrei, I created a little web page to visualize the relationship between the angle x and the tangent projection angle and approximate the answers inefficiently. I used that to create the illustrations in my question.


An answer to the following question should help:
Given that a cone was cut at angle x, what would be the ratio of radii in the elliptical conic section? A cylindrical section should have ratio abs(cos x) but a cone is more complex.


If I could get properties of an elliptical conic section at any distance away from the cone's vertex, would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha$ be the semi-aperture of the cone and $\theta$ (named $x$ in the question) the angle its axis forms with a given plane (see figure below). The projection of the cone onto the plane, for some values of $\theta$, is an angle whose sides are tangent to the projections of all the circular sections of the cone on the plane (twice angle $\delta$ in the figure).

If $ABCD$ is one such circular section of radius $h\tan\alpha$, its projection $A'B'C'D'$ is an ellipse with semi-axes $a=O'C'=OC=h\tan\alpha$ and
$b=O'B'=OB\sin\theta=h\tan\alpha\sin\theta$, while the distance from (the projection of) the vertex to the centre of the ellipse is $y_0=VO'=h\cos\theta$.

It is then a straightforward exercise to find the slope of the tangents:
$$
\tan\delta={a\over\sqrt{y_0^2-b^2}}=
{\tan\alpha\over\sqrt{\cos^2\theta-\tan^2\alpha\sin^2\theta}}.
$$

This formula works as long as the expression inside the square root is not negative, that is for $0\le\theta\le90{°}\!-\alpha$. For $\theta=90°\!-\alpha$ a generatrix of the cone is perpendicular to the plane and
$\delta=90°$.

For $\alpha=45°$, in particular:
$$
\tan\delta
={1\over\sqrt{\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta}}
={1\over\sqrt{\cos2\theta}}.
$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!  That worked very well.

I tested that with my interactive visualization and the angles line up perfectly through various cone slopes and various projection angles.

Comment: Thank you for this solution @intelligenti pauca. I'm wondering whether it is possible to generalise a solution including the cases, where the angle between the cone axis and the projected plane is equal or greater than 90 degrees. Any thoughts ? thanks a lot !

Comment: @mysterium If $\theta=90°$ then the projection is the whole plane. The case $\theta>90°$ doesn't make sense: $\theta$ is the angle between the axis of the cone and the plane (i.e. with the projection of that axis on the plane) and cannot be obtuse.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Intelligenti pauca. However, if one can imagine an ice-cream cone held upright with an extended arm, let's say at a geometry similar to the statue of liberty, and seen by their eyes, wouldn't the plane containing the eyes and the ice-cream cone axis (vertical in this case) make an obtuse angle ?  in addition, if one solves for tan  the above equation (going from a given projected half angle  to the original half angle  ), it seems that  can be defined for angles >90°. Or I'm mistaken somewhere ?

Comment: @mysterium In that case angle $\theta$ is the supplementary of your angle. Formally, you could use your angle as well, because $\cos(\pi-\theta)=-\cos\theta$ and the formula for $\tan\delta$ contains only $\cos^2\theta$.

Comment: ah, okay, many thanks again for the clarification @Intelligentipauca !

Answer (score 1):

When axis is tilted by $\beta$ and considering reduction of projected length in the denominator (simple figure, not drawn) we have new vertical angle for $90^{\circ}$ vertex angle:

$$2 \tan^{-1}\sec \beta$$

For the general case (using $\alpha $ in place of $x$). Let the tan of vertical angle at cone ( base radius $r$, height $h$ ) vertex be $T$.
Considering projections comparing tan of semi-vertical angles
$$ \tan \alpha=\dfrac{r}{h}$$
when the axis of symmetry is tilted by $ \beta$
$$ \tan \alpha_1=\dfrac{r \cos \beta}{h}$$
Dividing
$$ \sec \beta= \dfrac{\tan \alpha_1}{\tan \alpha}$$
Expressing half angle tangent $t$ in terms of the full angle tangent $T$ which is the projected angle between generators

$$\dfrac{{\dfrac{\sqrt{1+T1^2}-1}{T1}}}{{\dfrac{\sqrt{1+T^2}-1}{T}}} = \sec \beta, $$

an implicit equation between $ \tan^{-1} T_1 $ and $\tan^{-1} T. $